# How to update the URI of the webpage automatically?

Tags: php, html, count, uri

I have a table called files where there are columns such as id, name, webpage, visitors. There are list of files already in the table. Now I have created new columns called webpage and visitors. The webpage is the URI of the file and the visitors is the counter views of the file. The problem is that I wanted to update the webpage and visitors automatically using session but I can't. Can you please help me.

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once"config.php";

$webpage=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);


$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE webpage='$webpage'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows == 0){
mysql_query("How to update the URI ($webpage) automatically? in the files table inside the column webpage");

}else{

if (!isset($_SESSION['webpage'])){$_SESSION['webpage'] = 0;
mysql_query("UPDATE files SET visitors=visitors+1 WHERE webpage='$webpage'");}}

?>
```

Comment: What exactly is updating URL??
Can you explain with sample data?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your question, but just as a sidenote I would mention that you should not be using mysql_* functions anymore, as they have been deprecated. Use mysqli_* instead or PDO!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once"config.php";

$webpage=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);


$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE webpage='$webpage'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows == 0)
{
    $_SESSION['webpage'][] = $webpage;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (`id`,`name`,`webpage`,`visitors`) VALUES (null,'$name','$webpage','1')");
}
else
{
    if(is_array($_SESSION['webpage'])) && !in_array($webpage, $_SESSION['webpage'])))
    {
        $_SESSION['webpage'][] = $webpage;
        mysql_query("UPDATE files SET visitors=visitors+1 WHERE webpage='$webpage'");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ,the code 'mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (`id`,`name`,`webpage`,`visitors`) VALUES (null,'$name','$webpage','1')");' creates a new row which I don't to do this. I want to just update the details in the previous record. I might probably use UPDATE command? can you help me please

Comment: Yes thats fine.
But when No Record Found for webpage at that time you need to insert it in database also

Comment: $webpage=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE webpage='$webpage'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows == 0){
    mysql_query("UPDATE files SET id=id WHERE webpage='$webpage'");

I tried something like this, but doesn't work

Comment: But when I command the insert code then there will be duplicate column for a file i.e. a new column will insert where there will be new id, webpage and visitors. If I was able to update the webpage URI in the previous record then that would be much easier.